# Android: SpannableString with correctly formated numbers

Tags: java, android, textview, spannablestring

I would like to have a list of instructions that are correctly numbered in an enumeration. For that I use the SpannableString and I have the following code:

```
//Get string array from a sqLite Database
String [] instructions = MainActivity.sqLiteDataba.getPreparationInstructions(item);

//Create Spannable String Builder
int numberOfCurrentInstruction = 1;
SpannableStringBuilder builderInstructions =  new SpannableStringBuilder();
for (int i =0; i<instructions.length;i++) {
    if(instructions[i] == null ) {
        continue;
    }

    builderInstructions.append(numberOfCurrentInstruction + ". " + instructions[i] + "\n");
    numberOfCurrentInstruction++;
}
```

The output in a textview (called in a Fragment) does not look like the desired way, as you can see in the screenshot:
[image]

I would like the numbers to serve as "bullet points" meaning that if there is a linebreak in the textView, the following text should not start under the number but with a little bit of space. Any idea how I can do that?

**Update**: I tried the suggested approach posted below (Darkman) with the layout inflator but unfortunately only the very first item is being displayed. Here is the code from inside a Fragment:

```
    String [] instructions = MainActivity.sqLiteDB.getPreparationInstructions(item);

    
    int numberOfCurrentInstruction = 1;
    ViewGroup main = getView().findViewById(R.id.main);
    LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();

    for (int i =0; i<instructions.length;i++) {
        if(instructions[i] == null ) {
            continue;

        }

        ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup) inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom, main, true);
        ViewGroup customLayout = (ViewGroup) mainLayout.getChildAt(i);


        TextView num = (TextView) customLayout.getChildAt(0);
        TextView text = (TextView) customLayout.getChildAt(1);
        num.setText((numberOfCurrentInstruction) + ".");
        text.setText(instructions[i]);
        numberOfCurrentInstruction++;
    }
```

Here is the custom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_7ssp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_7ssp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the main.xml is inside a xml file for a fragment and looks like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/main">


    </LinearLayout>
```

The array `instructions` has 5 elements in it and none of them is null and the for loop is executed 5 times (I checked this by using LogTag). However, only the first instruction is displayed and the others not. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I guess you can solve it via XML. Split it into 2 textView.

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks for your comment. How shall I solve this problem with 2 textViews? I don't know when there are linebreaks before in the 1. textview that need to be also added to the 2. textview

Comment: https://www.vetbossel.in/android-recyclerview-example/ Try to do it via recycled view . Change XML for a item. But I don't know your source and I can wrong

Comment: @Alexander: I don't want to do this with a recyclerview but with a Spannable String

Comment: I don't think spannable can do that. I'd use two textviews though.

Comment: @Darkman: Thanks for your comment. I don't think that your suggested approach using two textviews works. How shall I solve this problem with 2 textViews? I don't know when there are linebreaks before in the 1. textview that need to be also added to the 2. textview.

Comment: @Darkman: Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you

Comment: would you please share the whole code , we want as per your implementation

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi: Thanks for your comment. As this question was posted about 1,5 years ago, I meanwhile used the accepted answer given below by using two TextViews via XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using two TextViews via XML like the following example.

**main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main">

</LinearLayout>
```

**custom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String[] str = {
        "Instruction 1: This is the first instruction that you have to do.",
        "Instruction 2: This is the second instruction that you have to do.",
        "Instruction 3: This is the third instruction that you have to do."
    };
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        ViewGroup main = findViewById(R.id.main);
        LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
        
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup) inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom, main, true);
            ViewGroup customLayout = (ViewGroup) mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
            TextView num = (TextView) customLayout.getChildAt(0);
            TextView text = (TextView) customLayout.getChildAt(1);
            num.setText((i+1) + ".");
            text.setText(str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks Darkman for your answer. I tried to implement your suggested approach using viewBinding (I don't use the findViewById approach) but unfortunately only the last instruction is displayed. I wrote an update. Any idea how I can implement your suggested approach using viewBinding in my case?

Comment: I'm sorry. That's as much as I could help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. The problem is, that I can't know in advance when designing the XML layout file, how many TextView I am going to have as this depends on the context. This is why I only have 1 textview and then your approach does not work. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? I don't understand how you tackled this problem in your approach. You also only define 1 TextView (both for number and for instructions). But you also make use of 2 xml layout files (main and custom). Would you mind elaborating a little bit more on that?

Comment: It seems that you don't understand what `LayoutInflator` does? It is for creating a tree view from an xml file. Because I used it in a loop, it will create 3 `custom.xml`s -- each `mainLayout` refers to a new `main.xml` after `custom.xml` has been inflated/put inside of the `LinearLayout` in `main.xml`, `customLayout` refers to the `LinearLayout` in `custom.xml`, `getChildAt(0)` for the first `TextView` and `getChildAt(0)` for the second `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I tried you suggested approach and the formatting is correct now. However, only the first instruction is being displayed and the others not (altough they are read from the database into the array). Any idea why this is happening? I posted an update with the new Java and XML code.

Comment: Don't know. Maybe change this `android:orientation="horizontal"` to this `android:orientation="vertical"` for the `main.xml`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and helped. In fact your suggested solution solved the problem. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer. Thanks for the tremendous effort.

Comment: Sure, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you use fixed-space font add several spaces after \n.
If you use monospace font adding spaces isn`t best way. In this case you can add symbols "1", "2" etc instead of spaces and set color for this symbols like background color.

Comment: Thanks Ilya for your answer. As expected, adding spaces after \n does not lead to the desired output because \n is added after each entry. But the problem is that there might be linebreaks in the textview and then I need these empty spaces. So your solution does solve the problem (it makes it even look worse)